# I cannot find my server name in Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have just set up Microsoft SQL Server 2012 to my computer. However, `server name:` is empty and I do not know how to handle with it.

Thanks all of you

Comment: Where does Server Name is empty?

Comment: You only need to know the local server name? Is this the issue?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569275/instance-servername-sql-server-2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which **edition** of SQL Server did you set up?

If you setup SQL Server 2012 **Express**, then the default instance name is `SQLEXPRESS`, so you should be able to use any of these server names:

- `.\SQLEXPRESS`
- `(local)\SQLEXPRESS`
- `localhost\SQLEXRPESS`

If you've set up any other edition of SQL Server 2012, and picked the default instance, then your server name would be:

- `.`
- `(local)`
- `localhost`

and if you picked a *different* instance name during setup - well, I hope you see how to concatenate together `.` (or `(local)` or `localhost`) with the instance name to get connected.

Comment: Hi Marc, why wouldn't you see this question as duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569275/instance-servername-sql-server-2012) mentioned by @EmmadKareem